# php, can't connect to mysql server

Tags: php, mysql

I'm on Windows and I'm trying to connect to a mysql database from php.

This is the code of the php file:

```
<?php
echo "Hello World!";
$link = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1:3306', 'root', '1234');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

When I run the php file on Apache server instead of getting a successful message I get a blank page.

I've tried with "localhost" instead of "127.0.0.1" but I got the same result.

What can I do?

thanks.

Comment: I guess that you get a php error which is not displayed for security reasons. Possible that the mysql extension is disabled try just for fun mysqli_connect

Comment: Can you access you MySQL by PHPMyAdmin or client?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. You stand at getting a deprecation warning notice.

Comment: @rekire: I tried mysqli_connect and got the same result.............@Seegan See: I'm new to php and mysql...........@drux: I'm using MySql Workbench and I can access MySql and the databases and I can also do queries.

Comment: @Fred -ii-: I added the error reporting and I got this message: "Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in C:\Apache\htdocs\php3\test.php on line 16"

Comment: Make sure those extensions are available, installed and properly configured. Including SQL installed.

Comment: @Fred -ii-: How can I check that the extensions are available and configured?

Comment: Consult http://serverfault.com/questions/444920/confirm-that-mysqli-extension-is-not-installed and http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php that should help a bit.

Comment: You can also make up with a `.php` file with this inside it `<?php phpinfo();` which will show you the modules list.

Comment: You were right Fred -ii-. I needed to enable the extensions on the php.ini file by removing the semicolon on **extension=php_mysql.dll** and **extension=php_mysqli.dll**. The links you posted helped me, thanks. Now my php code is connecting fine to the mysql database. You can post your answer so that I can label it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using latest version of php then, mysql is deprecated so you're better off using mysqli.

```
<?php
echo "Hello World!";
$link = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:3306', 'root', '1234');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: I've tried this and I added this error reporting code: error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);......and I got this message:  "Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in C:\Apache\htdocs\php3\test.php on line 16"